# Using Logging correctly in python

Tags: python, python-logging

My code looks like this. It is for image reshuffling in a couple of folders. Please assume that I have made all the required imports correctly.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'make_folders.log',  filemode= 'w', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)::%(message)s')




def get_path_list(directory: str) -> list:
    """
    Get a list of absolute paths of all the files in the directory.

    :param directory: Path to the directory from which the file paths are to be extracted.

    """
    path_list =[]

    for file in glob.glob(pathname=directory+'/*.png', recursive=True):
        path_list.append(file)

    return path_list


# Make a list of all the images contained in folder A and folder B
img_A = get_path_list(args.source_A)
img_B = get_path_list(args.source_B)

try:
    assert len(img_A) == len(img_B)

except AssertionError:
    logging.error("The number of images in source_A folder and source_B folder are not the same. Check input folders.")

# Find how many images we want in training, validation and test sets based on the length of list containing all image paths.
train_len = round(0.7 * len(img_A))
val_len = round(0.15 * len(img_A))
test_len = val_len

logging.info("Total number of training, validation and test images in destination folder A and B are {}, {} and {} respectively".format(train_len, val_len, test_len))
```

I am getting following error while using logging.info()

```
logging.info("Total number of training, validation and test images in destination folder A and B are {}, {} and {} respectively".format(train_len, val_len, test_len))
Message: 'Total number of training, validation and test images in destination folder A and B are 5265, 1128 and 1128 respectively'
Arguments: ()
```

can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code examples should be complete and self contained. We should be able to copy and paste your code, and replicate the problem you're facing; [mre]. Please edit your question to make it so that we can run your code and get the same output as you do. *(Ideally, logging to stdout, not to a file.)*

Comment: `I am getting following error while using` → here is no any error in your question

Comment: "Please assume that I have made all the required imports correctly." No. Include the required imports in your question, so that we don't have to make assumptions about what you have or have not done correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a [new logger instance yourself](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/python-logging-guide/#7howtocreateanewlogger) and not use the root logger as that gets confusing fast.

An example:

```py
# Import the logging package and a file handler that can rotate your logs automatically
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

# Create logger and set a name for the logger
# You can write a name yourself, or use the __name__ variable 
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Add a consolehandler so your log is printed on your screen
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
loglevel = logging.DEBUG
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s")
# Filehandler so you can read back your logs when the script has quit
# It automatically rotates the log after it reaches a size of 1 MegaByte
# You can configure it however you want, just see the docs
fileHandler = RotatingFileHandler("your_log.log", maxBytes=1 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=3)

# Set loglevel of all handlers and the logger itself.
consoleHandler.setLevel(loglevel)
fileHandler.setLevel(loglevel)
logger.setLevel(loglevel)  # Not entirely sure if this line is needed

# Assign the formatter you defined earlier to the two handlers
consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add the consolehandler, but check if there's a handler already
# If you don't check in some situations you might get duplicate handlers added to your logger, resulting in all your log lines to be printend multiple times.
if len(logger.handlers) == 0:
    logger.debug("Adding new log handler, none exists yet.")
    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```

Now if you want to print a line to the log you can do:

```py
logger.debug("This message is only visible when the debug level is set")
logger.info("An informative message")
logger.warning("A warning to the user")
logger.error("An error has occurred, please check...")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error comes from:

```py
format='%(asctime)::%(message)s'
```

Change it to:

```py
format='%(asctime)s %(message)s'
```

And it works.

Additionally, newer versions of Python suggest we use f-strings instead of string formatting:

```py
logging.info(f"Total number of training, validation and test images in destination folder A and B are {train_len}, {val_len} and {test_len} respectively")
```